# NEo4j - REMOVE on relationship property not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am facing a strange behavior with **REMOVE** on relationship property. The property is not getting removed even after the query execution. The temp is used for **CASE** condition check. After that I have to remove the property, which is not happening accordingly.

Here is my query:

```
MERGE (a { word:"aut" })-[r:jsim]->(b { word:"et" })
ON 
CREATE SET r.temp = FALSE ON 
MATCH SET r.temp = TRUE 
WITH r,
CASE r.val
WHEN r.temp
THEN [a]
ELSE [] END AS toDo UNWIND toDo AS a
MATCH (a)-[s]->(b { word:"voluptas" })
SET r.val = s.val
WITH r, r.temp AS result
REMOVE r.temp
RETURN r
```

Here is the [console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=c75h5u) for test. Please some one find where I am missing.

Afetr some suggestions I changed the query to:

```
MERGE (a { word:"aut" })-[r:jsim]->(b { word:"et" })
ON 
CREATE SET r.temp = -1  
WITH r,
CASE 
WHEN r.temp = -1
THEN [a]
ELSE [] END AS toDo UNWIND toDo AS a
MATCH (a)-[s]->(b { word:"voluptas" }) RETURN a
```

Here, the node a is forwarded, which is also not returned, the word **review** is present in my graph connected to a.

Comment: Have you updated the console? I don't see a word=review in there

Comment: Sorry, Console has not updated. That query ran on my local machine. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove `r.temp`,  `MATCH (a)-[s]->(b { word:"voluptas" })` should match something- from the console you shared, it looks like it won't and so the rest of the query won't be executed. This includes setting `r.val` which you use in the `CASE`.

Is it your intent to `MERGE (a { word:"aut" })-[r:jsim]->(b { word:"et" })` correct? You seem to have two nodes with word="aut" but that might be what you expect.

**Update based on edited question**

It looks like you expect to find a relation between the `word:"voluptas"` and the `word:"aut"` which you created/matched via the merge. However, there is no such relationship.
Executing

```
MATCH (b { word:"voluptas" })-[r]-(c { word:"aut" })
RETURN b,r,c
```

returns one relation to a node with `word:"aut"` but this is ***not the same node*** that was created in the merge. You'll find you have two nodes with `word:"aut"` in this graph.

So, I am assuming this is not what you expect. You can change the query to first merge nodes and then the relationship between them to ensure that you have only one relationship between those two nodes that already exist. Your updated query would now look like

```
MERGE (a { word:"aut" })
MERGE (b { word:"et" })
MERGE (a)-[r:jsim]->(b)
ON 
CREATE SET r.temp = -1
WITH r,
CASE
WHEN r.temp = -1
THEN [a]
ELSE [] END AS toDo UNWIND toDo AS a
MATCH (a)-[s]->(b { word:"voluptas" })
RETURN a
```

Remember that MERGE will not look at partial patterns- it will either match the entire pattern or create it. Since it could not match the entire pattern, it was created i.e. both nodes and the relation, even though the node with `word:"aut"` existed.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the query is not executing it seems. I will look into it once.

Comment: Looking Strange, I edited my question upon your suggestion. Even the simple MATCH query is terminating the execution. Please have a look into it.

Comment: The first time the new query is executed, it creates the whole path (a { word:"nothing" })-[r:jsim]->(b { word:"equal" }). a never gets a chance to be related to word:"review" so it won't be matched.

Comment: I did not get what exactly you are saying. Can you please elaborate this.